# Arangodb: bikes filtered by timestamp and coordinates

Tags: arangodb

I have a data structure like this:

[image]

red vertices are POSITION
cyan vertices are BIKE
pink vertex is USER

```
GRAPH TD

((BIKE)) -- LOCATED -->((POSITION))
```

where BIKE is one with many POSITION associated

every position have latitude and longitude property and a timestamp

I would like to find all bikes who's position is near 40Km from a coordinate pair, not older than 48 Hrs

what I'm doing so far is:

```
FOR pos IN NEAR(positions, 45.5063575, 9.24157653499384, 40, "distance")
        FILTER pos.timestamp >= DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), "PT48H")
        SORT pos.timestamp DESC, pos.distance DESC
        RETURN {'position': pos,'bike':(FOR bike IN OUTBOUND pos located RETURN  bike)}
```

but this query is returning all positions with their bikes, I would like the last position (closest in time) and the belonging bike

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that:

```
FOR pos IN WITHIN(positions, 45.5063575, 9.24157653499384, 40, "distance")
  FILTER pos.timestamp >= DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), "PT48H")
  SORT pos.timestamp DESC
  FOR b IN OUTBOUND pos located
    COLLECT bike = b INTO bike_positions
    RETURN {'bike': bike, 'position': bike_positions[0].pos}
```

**Note**: You should use `WITHIN` instead of `NEAR`.

**UPDATE** after @Loki comment:

```
FOR pos IN positions
  FILTER pos.timestamp >= DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), "PT200H") AND 
         GEO_DISTANCE([45.47942614827045, 9.24157653499384], pos.coordinates)
  SORT pos.timestamp DESC     
  FOR b IN OUTBOUND pos located
    COLLECT bike = b INTO bike_positions
    RETURN {'bike': bike, 'position': bike_positions[0].pos}
```

Comment: since WITHIN is deprecated (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-geo.html#within)  I tried to rewrite the query using DISTANCE().                            
```FOR pos IN positions
    FILTER pos.timestamp >= DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), "PT200H")
    LET d = DISTANCE(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude, 45.47942614827045, 9.24157653499384)
    FILTER d <= 40
    SORT d ASC
      FOR b IN OUTBOUND pos located
        COLLECT bike = b INTO bike_positions
        RETURN {'bike': bike, 'position': bike_positions[0].pos}```.  what do you think?

Comment: In new notation, probably it's even better to use GEO_DISTANCE with geo-index. I will update my answer with that example